# Why my add Event listener doesn't work correctly?

Tags: easeljs

Here is my code.

```
var _this = this;
var i = 0;
var object;

for (i=1 ; i <5 ; i++){
    object = new lib.A ();
    object.x = 50 * i;
    object.y = 100;
    _this.addChild (object);
    object.on ("tick" , position , true)
}

function position(){
    object.y += 1;
}
```

I have an object in the library and create and add to stage 4 number.
I want to move down all object with the addEventListener (tick), but it moves last object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the clicked object. In your code, the `object` variable changes in your for-loop, so at the end it is the last known value. Instead use the clicked target from the event (passed in the click handler):

```
function position(event){
    event.currentTarget.y += 1;
}
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have a `stage` somewhere in your code to depict the canvas, as in:

`stage = new createjs.Stage("gameCanvas");`

I think you're missing `stage.update(event)` as in:

```
function position(event){
  //....update the poositions
  stage.update(event);
}
```